# Cabal fails to parse build-depends in test-suite block

Tags: haskell, cabal, haskell-stack

I am trying to add testing to a package I am working on (I am using stack). Everything worked up until this point. I am running the following versions (as up-to-date as my ubuntu will get):

```
cabal-install version 1.22.6.0
using version 1.22.4.0 of the Cabal library

Stack: Version 0.1.4.0, Git revision 3a665fe1bc52776041a1c25cc47734e691805b6c (1724 commits) X86_64
```

This is the offending section:

```
Test-Suite test-one
  main-is: Test.hs
  type: exitcode-stdio-1.0
  hs-source-dirs: test
  build-depends: base >= 4.7 && < 5
               , scotty >= 0.10.2
               , scotty-login-session
               , text
               , wai
               , wai-extra
               , HUnit
               , HTTP-4000
```

and this is the error that stack/cabal give when trying to build or test:

```
Unable to parse cabal file <mypackage>.cabal: NoParse "build-depends" 44
```

that 44 is the build-depends line above.

What is happening here? I followed the Cabal User Guide, and my google-fu turned up nothing. The rest of the cabal file is linked [here](http://lpaste.net/141589) for reference.

My system is ubuntu 14.04 LTS if that helps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The last line should be:

```
                 , HTTP
```

and not `HTTP-4000`. Perhaps you want `, HTTP >= 4000`.

Here is some more info on the problem...

This is the code in the `Cabal` library to parse a package name [(link)](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/Cabal-1.22.4.0/docs/src/Distribution.Package.html#PackageName)

```
instance Text PackageName where
  disp (PackageName n) = Disp.text n
  parse = do
    ns <- Parse.sepBy1 component (Parse.char '-')
    return (PackageName (intercalate "-" ns))
    where
      component = do
        cs <- Parse.munch1 Char.isAlphaNum
        if all Char.isDigit cs then Parse.pfail else return cs
        -- each component must contain an alphabetic character, to avoid
        -- ambiguity in identifiers like foo-1 (the 1 is the version number).
```

Note the comment at the end. Perhaps at one time `build-depends:` accepted the syntax `name-version`, e.g. `aeson-0.10.0.0`, and later this was changed to require use of the relational operators, e.g. `aeson == 0.10.0.0`.

Now that we always use the relational operators perhaps it might be possible to allow package names with an all numeric component.

In any case, something like `foo-123x` is a valid package name since the second component isn't all numeric.

Comment: ahh yes of course. the error's line number and HTTP's version number (wtf?) threw me off. Thanks!

Comment: yeah - the line number is not accurate. any error in the block will be reported at the first line in the block, unfortunately. It's interesting that cabal doesn't allow that package name.